# How can I get the GRUB menu to appear only when I press shift on a dual boot system to give me the option of booting Windows?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a dual boot system. I mainly work with Linux and rarely with Windows, so I want to set Linux to boot by default without bringing up the GRUB menu, but to bring up the menu if I press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> so I can boot into Windows.

I already hide the grub menu and boot by default with Linux and only shows the GRUB menu when I press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, but this only works if I disable the **Look for other OS** option, and as a result of that Windows doesn't appear as an option in the menu, so I can't boot into it!

How can I get the configuration I want?

Comment: @DavidFoerster since that question describes a different situation, could you indicate which of its answers OP should implement?

Comment: @Zanna: Good idea! I mean [tomodachi's answer](/a/249530/175814) specifically.

Comment: I am currently using this configuration but I rather getting the menu only if I press, this is bring me the menu every time. But of course this is the better solution so far.

Answer (score -1):

You need to edit as root the file `/etc/default/grub` and modify a few lines at the top to the hidden timeout. In my case it looks as follows:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-101-generic"
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
```

Comment: The menu should come up every time with that configuration... you seem to have an extra customised `GRUB_DEFAULT` line, but since it's commented out (starts with `#`), it won't do anything at all. So, what are you talking about?

Comment: `GRUB_TIMEOUT=10` will give you 10s to select an OS (windows in his case) otherwise it will boot into Linux.

Comment: Yeah, but that's the default configuration in dual boot. OP doesn't want to see the GRUB menu unless they press shift